# Python Alarm Clock Doesn't Break

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement, while-loop, alarm

I tried to make a simple Alarm Clock without using Tkinter. The Alarm runs and starts a countdown of every second but when it gets to the set time that the Alarm is supposed to go off, it continues to run. How would I make the Alarm Break and open my web browser to play the selected song in mylines at the set time?

```
lines = open("Links.txt").read().splitlines()
mylines = random.choice(lines)
print(mylines)  


name = raw_input("Enter your name: ")

print("Hello, " + name)

alarm_hour = input("Enter the hour you want to wake up: ")
alarm_min = input("Enter the min of the hour you want to wake up: ")

print("You want to wake up at: {0:02}:{1:02}").format(alarm_hour, alarm_min)
alarm = Alarm(alarm_hour, alarm_min)
#print (time.strftime())
clock = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
while True:
    if clock != alarm:
    print "The time is: " + clock
    clock = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    time.sleep(1)

    if alarm == clock:
    #webbrowser.open(newlist[pick])
        print "Alarm Now"
        webbrowser.open(mylines)
        break
```

Comment: You're comparing an Alarm to the return of `time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")`. I can't see `alarm == clock` ever being true. What is an Alarm?

Comment: You seem to be comparing string to an object. I don't see the Alarm definition but maybe the string representation of it is not what you expect it to be?

Comment: Also, even if you fix that, your code could easily miss an alarm. Let's say it's `08:29:59.977`. Then you `sleep(1)`, and next time through the loop it's `08:30:01.013`. If your alarm was set for `08:30:00`, you'd have jumped right over it. You probably want to compare `alarm <= clock`, and then disable the alarm when it fires. (If you want it to fire every day, either keep track of whether the alarm has fired today, or use a `datetime` rather than a `time` and reset the alarm to "same time tomorrow" after it fires. But if you only want to fire it once, you can keep it simpler.)

Comment: Also, you may be better ff using an existing, tested scheduler, either one that comes with your OS (Windows Scheduled Tasks, cron, launchd, etc.), or a Python one (the stdlib `sched` or a simpler and more powerful third-party lib like APScheduler).